# Liste mit "Denk-Verben"

Tags: verb, reference

Ich suche Quellen - gedruckt oder online - für eine möglichst umfangreiche, wenn nicht gar vollständige Liste deutscher "Denk-Verben", also Verben wie `denken`, `wissen`, `verstehen`, `erkennen`, `glauben`, `wollen`, `erinnern`, `vergessen`, `vorstellen`, `wünschen` usw., also von Verben, die entweder Tätigkeiten des Verstands bezeichnen (`denken`, `überlegen`, `betrachten`) oder bewusste Wahrnehmungen, die dem Ich zugeschrieben werden (`ich empfinde Angst`, `ich fühle mich ausgebrannt`).

Comment: Was genau sind für Dich "Denk-Verben"? Ist es Zufall oder Absicht, daß in Deinen Beispielen zwar "glauben" vorkommt, aber nicht "fühlen"?

Comment: @Matthias Ich hätte die Liste meiner Beispiele länger machen können, dann hätte sie auch `fühlen` umfasst. Mit "Denk-Verben" meine ich alle Verben, die mentale Vorgänge beschreiben, also Tätigkeiten des Verstands (`denken`, `überlegen`, `betrachten`) ebenso wie bewusste Wahrnehmungen, die dem Ich zugeschrieben werden (`ich empfinde Angst`, `ich fühle mich ausgebrannt`).

Comment: Probier einen Online-Thesaurus (es gibt mehrere).

Comment: @dirkt Kannst du ein Beispiel nennen und wie ich dort die Denk-Verben herausfiltere? Wenn ich einfach nur Synonyme zu `denken` suche, gehen mir eine Menge Verben durch die Lappen. Es geht mir ja gerade darum, auch mir weniger bekannte Worte nicht zu übersehen, sonst würde ich einfach die Worte aufschreiben, die mir einfallen.

Comment: Die Frage ist unklar, vage und zu breit gefasst. Wenn fühlen und empfinden inkludiert sind, dann ist das Feld äußerst weit. Antworten werden kein Ende finden - es ufert aus und läd zu subjektiven Spekulationen ein.

Comment: @Carlster Re: Your edit. The first sentence ends with "usw.", the second sentence begins with "Gedruckt", which must be capitalized.

Comment: @userunknown (... So wie ich die Frage verstehe sucht OP nach einer Referenz... es ist nicht gemeint, dass wir eine Liste schreiben sollen. Daher ist die Frage, was ein Denkverb genau ist, zweitrangig. Ich finde, die Frage hat ihre Berechtigung und sollte erlaubt werden.

Comment: @userunknown Welchen Sinn hat das, 4h nachdem der OP eine Antwort akzeptiert und im Kommentar vermerkt hat, daß das ziemlich genau das war, wonach er suchte?

Comment: @Matthias: Die eine gemeinsame Vorstellung davon zu erarbeiten, welche Fragen on-topic und welche off-topic sind. Da man gar nicht ahnt welche Fragen alle kommen kann man das nicht vorab klären, sondern muss an Hand von Beispielen immer wieder evaluieren, was geht und was nicht, was angemessen ist und was nicht. Fragen sollen gerade nicht nur den aktuellen Frager befriedigen, sondern für andere auch nützliche Antworten liefern. Die Psychologie liefert 9000 Erklärungen, wieso die Antwort akzeptiert wurde - eine wäre, um zu dementieren, dass es keine gute Antwort auf die Frage geben kann.

Comment: @userunknown OK, verstehe. Also "unclear what you're asking" - nein, ich finde das Ziel der Frage ist zumindest seit dem erklärenden Kommentar hinreichend beschrieben; und um das für neue Besucher schneller erfaßbar zu machen, habe ich gerade eben die Frage editiert. "too broad" käme in Frage, aber da nach einer möglichst großen Liste gefragt wurde, sehe ich da erst mal kein großes Risiko - das könnte man abwarten.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ich weiß von keiner solchen Liste. Möglicherweise mußt Du sie Dir selbst erstellen. Du könntest dabei so vorgehen, daß Du durch Recherche und eigenes Nachdenken eine Startmenge bildest und diese dann unter Verwendung eines Thesaurus erweiterst. D.h. Du schlägst jedes Wort Deiner Startmenge im Thesaurus nach und nimmst alle Synonyme auf, die Dir als zutreffend erscheinen, und verfährst so auch mit den neu hinzukommenden Wörtern, bis Du den transitiven Abschluß erreichst, also keine neuen Wörter mehr hinzukommen.

Beim Erstellen der Startmenge könnten Dir helfen:

- [diese Dissertation](http://miami.uni-muenster.de/Record/baa0e63e-ba83-43de-b16a-4f29a5d62bbd)
- Googeln nach "kognitive Verben". Dabei findest Du zum Beispiel

http://www.ecvet-info.de/_media/TaxTab_Verbenliste_deutsch.pdf

http://www.studienseminar.info/dokumente_ungeschuetzt/liste_verben_lernzielformulierung.doc

http://dppd.ubbcluj.ro/germ/material/CURRICULUM%20HERMANNSTADT/verben%20zur%20Formulierung%20von%20Lernzielen.pdf

Sicher bei weitem nicht das Ergebnis, das Du Dir erhofft hast - aber vielleicht doch hilfreich.

Comment: Schon die Liste in der Dissertation erscheint mir die Mehrzahl, wenn nicht gar alle gegenwärtig gebräuchlichen Verben zu enthalten. Ausgehend von dieser Liste werde ich die wenigen fehlenden sicher finden. Herzlichen Dank!

Answer (score 0):

Allen, denen zusätzliche Verben einfallen, steht es frei, sie alphabetisch einzuordnen. Vorschläge für eine Gliederung in Bereiche können in den Kommentaren gemacht werden. Ob ein Verb aus der Liste genommen werden sollte, kann man mit einem Sternchen* zum Ausdruck bringen. Dieser Post ist "community wiki", das bedeutet, dass niemand Reputation dafür bekommt.

ahnen

annehmen

argwöhnen

ausschließen

beabsichtigen

bedenken

begreifen

beurteilen

bewerten

bezweifeln

denken

durchschauen

durchblicken

dünken

erfassen

einordnen

ergründen

erkennen

erinnern

erwägen

finden

folgern

grübeln

imaginieren

meinen

nachdenken

planen

reflektieren

schließen

schlussfolgern

überlegen

urteilen

vergessen

vermuten

vernehmen

verstehen

vorhaben

vorstellen

wahrnehmen

wähnen

wissen

wollen

zweifeln